# Copy data with conditions based on sorted column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code that one user gave me works. In Sheet1, ColumnA, Row 2 - the values are copied and pasted, then sorted alphabetically into Sheet2, ColumnB, Row 3.

Now I want Sheet 1, ColumnB, Row2 to paste into Sheet2, ColumnE, Row3 based on the conditions within Sheet1, ColumnA.

Each name is next to a category (H, H/R, H/R/I). When I paste into the new sheet, these categories are sorted alphabetically and I want the names to still match their categories (NOT BE SORTED).

What I start with:
[image: Excel Columns 1]

What I want the result to be:
[image: Excel Columns 2]

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    
'Declaration of variable
lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' 1. Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCol As String = "a"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dCol As String = "b"
    Const dfRow As Long = 3
    ' Other
    Const Msg As String = "Copied column sorted."
    
    ' 2. Reference the workbook ('wb')
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 3. Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Reference the source first cell ('sfCell').
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol)
    ' Using '.End(xlUp)', reference the source last cell ('slCell').
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp)
    ' Using the source first and last cells, reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    ' 4. Reference the destination range ('drg').
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Reference the destination first cell ('dfCell')..
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dfRow, dCol)
    ' Using '.Resize' and the number of rows of the source range
    ' ('srg.rows.count') on the destination first cell,
    ' make the destination range the same size as the source range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' 5. Copy the values from the source range to the destination range.
    ' This is the most efficient way to copy values and is called
    ' 'Copying by Assignment'.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' 6. Sort the destination range.
    drg.Sort drg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    ' 7. Inform so you don't have to worry if you have clicked the button.
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    
        'Conditional if statement that copies "a's" in Sheet 1, Column A and pastes in Sheet 2, Column B
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "H" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Copy
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastrow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i + 1).Select
                        
            ActiveSheet.Paste
    
        'Conditional if statement that copies "a's" in Sheet 1, Column A and pastes in Sheet 2, Column B
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "H/R"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Copy
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastrow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i + 1).Select
                        
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        'Conditional if statement that copies "a's" in Sheet 1, Column A and pastes in Sheet 2, Column B
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "H/R/I"
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Copy
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            lastrow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i + 1).Select
                        
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        'Deletes empty cells and shifts "a's" upward
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & i).Value = ""
            Columns("E:E").Select
            Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            
        End If
      
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: is the sort working how you want it to? and i assume that in Sheet1 the column is not totally full of data?  in this case you could use `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:B" & rows.count).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & rows.count - 1).Value`  value assignment being slightly more efficient that using the clipboard.  The other change you will see is the ranges being adjusted.  you then may also have to sort `Range("B3:B" & rows.count)` let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I made the changes you suggested above and when I copy and paste into the Column B of Sheet 2, it affects all the Rows instead of starting on Row 3. Row 1 contains the title and Row 2 contains the subtitles, so I don't want those changed or sorted but unfortunately it is being sorted with everything else. Do you have any suggestion on how to prevent this?

Comment: did you make the change to the sort as mentioned?  also prior to the sort is the right data coming across in rows 3+

Comment: This is my new code. What am I doing wrong? 

Private Sub Button1_Click()

'Copy column "A" from Sheet1 into Column "B" of Sheet2 (Unsorted values)

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:B" & Rows.Count).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count - 1).Value

'Sort the column 'B' using excel funcion 'Sort'

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("B:B").Sort key1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:B" & Rows.Count), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Comment: If you have new code, you can *edit your question* and add it there: it will be much easier to read.

Comment: those should be elseif statements with the condition on the same line and a then at the end i.e. `Elseif CONDITION Then`

Answer (score 2):

### Copy Column Sorted

**Step By Step**

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    
    ' 1. Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dCol As String = "B"
    Const dfRow As Long = 3
    ' Other
    Const Msg As String = "Copied column sorted."
    
    ' 2. Reference the workbook ('wb')
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' 3. Reference the source range ('srg').
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Reference the source first cell ('sfCell').
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol)
    ' Using '.End(xlUp)', reference the source last cell ('slCell').
    Dim slCell As Range: Set slCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp)
    ' Using the source first and last cells, reference the source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    ' 4. Reference the destination range ('drg').
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Reference the destination first cell ('dfCell')..
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dfRow, dCol)
    ' Using '.Resize' and the number of rows of the source range
    ' ('srg.rows.count') on the destination first cell,
    ' make the destination range the same size as the source range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' 5. Copy the values from the source range to the destination range.
    ' This is the most efficient way to copy values and is called
    ' 'Copying by Assignment'.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' 6. Sort the destination range.
    drg.Sort drg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    ' 7. Inform so you don't have to worry if you have clicked the button.
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is such a nice layout and answer to the original and for people to follow!